# Jqplot graph is not displaying inside nested div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqplot

I'm testing a jqplot mixed bar and line graph inside a JSF2.2 template client xhtml page that has a tabbed view. If I put the graph inside the tabbed view it will not not show. If I put it outside the view it shows:

```
<div id="datanalytics">
<div class="w3-layout-container">
<div id="chart2"> </div> 
</div>
</div>
```

The above just comes out as a blank area where the graph should be. I see  no JS errors in either Chrome or Firefox (Firebug). If I put the graph outside the main div like this, it will show perfectly:

```
<div id="chart2"> </div> 
<div id="datanalytics">
<div class="w3-layout-container">
</div>
</div>
```

I am including the following JS at the bottom of the xhtml page:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  var line1 = [['Cup Holder Pinion Bob', 7], ['Generic Fog Lamp', 9], ['HDTV Receiver', 15],
  ['8 Track Control Module', 12], [' Sludge Pump Fourier Modulator', 3],
  ['Transcender/Spice Rack', 6], ['Hair Spray Danger Indicator', 18]];
  var line2 = [['Nickle', 28], ['Aluminum', 13], ['Xenon', 54], ['Silver', 47],
  ['Sulfer', 16], ['Silicon', 14], ['Vanadium', 23]];

  var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [line1, line2], {
  series: [{renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer}, {xaxis: 'x2axis', yaxis: 'y2axis'}],
  axesDefaults: {
  tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
  tickOptions: {
  angle: 30
  }
  },
  axes: {
  xaxis: {
  renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
  },
  x2axis: {
  renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
  },
  yaxis: {
  autoscale: true
  },
  y2axis: {
  autoscale: true
  }
  }
  });

  });

  </script>
```

In my xhtml template page I have the following libraries added (at the end of the body tag so that the scripts execute after page loading):

```
    <h:outputScript name="js/jqplot/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.js"/>
    <h:outputScript name="js/jqplot/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js"/>
    <h:outputScript name="js/jqplot/chartExtender.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/jqplot/excanvas.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/jqplot/chartExtender.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/jqplot/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/jqplot/jqplot.barRenderer.js" />
```

**The problem is solved if I don't use      $(document).ready(function () and instead use:**

```
  function processChartAsClick() {

 .......
 }
```

I think this is because the script does not get fired inside a tabbed view because the tabbed view is a separate Jquery UI event, but putting it outside the tabbed view fires the event when the document is loaded? 
Would appreciate any clarification on this. Thank you!

Comment: Besides the way you include the scripts, I don't see anything JSF related. Does it work if you include them in the plain html way? And if it works outside the nested div it is certainly not JSF related

Comment: You are right. In this specific question the problem is entirely jQuery / JS related, but this problem has drawn my attention on issues to do with JSF events in nested tags. I don't know whether that is JSF related or again purely JS related but I will post that separately as I managed to find solutions to this particular question. I would also like to remove the JSF tag to this question but I don't see how I can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simply to give the script its own (autonomous) function since the document ready method is fired upon page loading. This means that if the JS/Jquery script is inside a div which uses its own JS UI function, then it will get ignored unless the script is part of the nested div JS function.

I added a button and corresponding function and the chart is now showing:

```
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="showChart()">Show the chart </button>

<script>

 function showChart() {
 JS code here
 .......
}
</script>
```

While this renders the chart it throws some more questions about how to handle events in nested divs in a JSF applications, but that needs to be posted separately.